# Using Python to Resize Images when Greater than 1280 on either side

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to use Python to resize any image based on the following 2 conditions.

1) If an image is landscape, get width, if greater than `1280` resize image width to 1280 **maintaining aspect ratio**.

2) If an image is portrait, get height, if greater than`1280` resize height to 1280 **maintaining aspect ratio**.

In Python what is the best package/approach to achieve this? Without knowing what to use this is how I see it working.

Pseudocode:

```
If image.height > image.width:
  size = image.height

If image.height < image.width:
  size = image.width

If size > 1280:
  resize maintaining aspect ratio
```

I was looking at `Pillow` (PIL).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it via PIL, something like this:

```
import Image

MAX_SIZE = 1280
image = Image.open(image_path)
original_size = max(image.size[0], image.size[1])

if original_size >= MAX_SIZE:
    resized_file = open(image_path.split('.')[0] + '_resized.jpg', "w")
    if (image.size[0] > image.size[1]):
        resized_width = MAX_SIZE
        resized_height = int(round((MAX_SIZE/float(image.size[0]))*image.size[1])) 
    else:
        resized_height = MAX_SIZE
        resized_width = int(round((MAX_SIZE/float(image.size[1]))*image.size[0]))

    image = image.resize((resized_width, resized_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(resized_file, 'JPEG')
```

Additionaly, you can remove original image and rename resized.